How "the unity of opposites" represents non-duality?

The existence or identity of a thing (or situation) depends on the
co-existence of at least two conditions which are opposite to each
other, yet dependent on each other and presupposing each other, within
a field of tension.


In his philosophy, Hegel ventured to describe quite a few cases of
"unity of opposites", including the concepts of Finite and Infinite,
Force and Matter, Identity and Difference, Positive and Negative, Form
and Content, Chance and Necessity, Cause and effect, Freedom and
Necessity, Subjectivity and Objectivity, Means and Ends, Subject and
Object, and Abstract and Concrete.

I can understand that in nature everything exists in temporary balance, usually the balance of opposites.
But I am missing the philosophical understanding of "the unity of opposites".

What particularly are you looking for, maybe I can answer it? But because minds tend to polarize and break things apart, likely you will never find a Philosophical understanding of unity. You can see it if you look the right way long enough. Then you will never lose sight of it again. Explaining it is probably impossible though. What did Hegel say about it?

"Long live the proletarian hegemony"

I think I missed that one in my education, sorry. Another lead?

Wikipedia's source is McGill-Parry, who count 6 different interpretations of the "unity of opposites". The one alluded to in the OP quote, the 'identity' of polar opposites is explained thus:"In any ordinary sense, polar opposites, or contraries, such as black and white, hot and cold, cannot be identical. But when you abstract sufficiently from circumstances, contraries such as "positive" and "negative" are interchangeable and indistinguishable." High levels of abstraction remove presuppositions that enable the distinction

I have once conducted a very long conversation about the concept of unity of opposites: opponentity: unity of opposites. It's very long developing slowly.

There is a booklet All is One weighing in at all of 15 pages. [Starts at pg 3] If the question of non-duality calls you do spend a little time perusing it

The sense of 'Nonduality' that I mean by the word is not a Philosophical position, but I will put this answer out anyway, because it is an Exit sign off the endless freeway of Philosophy discourse. Freeways are a means to get somewhere, not a destination, so you should get off when you like the surroundings.
Various folks "describe" the nondual experience differently, but with some commonalities, which is how we know it isn't just a bunch of people prattling about their delusions. The origin sense of it described by two teachers that I know is in terms of "The Two Real Things" - the Void, and Experience.
Experience is all actuality, everything we know by experiencing it, and everything that is, that we can know. Some people call it "that which is", such as Gary Zukav in "The Dancing Wu Li Masters". Some people just call it "what is", like Byron Katie. One famous quote is:

Things can be, and their Being is grounded in Nothing's ability to noth -- Kenneth Burke - "Language as Symbolic Action"

Which brings us to symbols. Nonduality is called Non-Symbolic Consciousness by researcher Jeffery Martin.
The Void is not referred to as often, and being one of the Two Real Things, leaving it out is part of what causes the confusion. The Void is all possibility, no actuality. Clearly it is necessary or there could be no coming to be of things that aren't, and no way to distinguish what is because we couldn't conceive of anything else. Humans stick their toes in here all the time, but of course, can't tell how warm the water is, so they don't accept it.
It is possible to see the distinction vanish. That is when someone is referred to as 'nondual'.  But, it is not on the freeway, you have to get off to see it.

freeway... nice metaphor! [Until we get addicted...]

The unity comes from the fact of consciousness being independent of the particular objects arising in consciousness at any moment of time. There is a stream of consciousness in which opposites arise and cannot exist independent of each other. The base consciousness can be represented as the handle of a bident. The opposites which arise in the stream of consciousness can be represented as the two forks of the bident. There is one bident (a unity) with a handle (consciousness) and two forks (concepts of opposites arising in consciousness). Consciousness transcends the stream of consciousness. Ordinarily we get lost in the stream of consciousness and lose sight of the unity of all things in the mind.

Gosh, way better than what I was thinking of saying!

This answer gets my +1. But you should add yours as well @ScottRowe.  I was going to say about the same ballpark — viz. The useful answer is likely more psychological than ontological. And within psychological, it would be more emotive than cognitive.

@SystemTheory - You might like A.N.Whitehead's Process and Reality (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_and_Reality) - Your approach seems very similar to Whitehead's.

@mudskipper - I once read that Thesaurus means Treasury in Greek. A group of treasure-words. One can see that conventional terms of art used in science, engineering, law, psychotherapy, and the like, are sets of treasure words that enable special modes of self-other communication. My philosophy is simple. There is a field of awareness, above I call it base consciousness, and there are items of recognition, forming associations, that arise and pass away in my otherwise empty field of awareness. I use associations to encode or decode the meaning of words in modes of self-other communication.

One variation of "unity of opposites" is found in Brouwer's notion of the "twoity", the core intuition, according to him, of mathematics. The SEP quotes Brouwer's explanation of this first, most basic assumption of intuitionism (italics are mine):

Completely separating mathematics from mathematical language and hence from the phenomena of language described by theoretical logic, recognizing that intuitionistic mathematics is an essentially languageless activity of the mind having its origin in the perception of a move of time. This perception of a move of time may be described as the falling apart of a life moment into two distinct things, one of which gives way to the other, but is retained by memory. If the twoity thus born is divested of all quality, it passes into the empty form of the common substratum of all twoities. And it is this common substratum, this empty form, which is the basic intuition of mathematics. (Brouwer, Cambridge Lectures)

This basic intuition is a Kantian intuition of time or change: "one_thing-and_then-another_thing", "two-in-one". It does seem, somehow, that we cannot fully grasp or describe that, since it also seems to be consciousness (experienced self-awareness, self-reflection) in its most basic manifestation (which requires memory or a self as object to refer back to). In Brouwer's philosophy this is the basis for the natural numbers (counting). Note that this notion is not the abstract notion of a "moment in time" - which is like a point in space, without extension or duration - but the notion of a concrete, experienced "now", "a move of time".
When you start thinking about this, you can ask, for instance: "How can any thing (any determinate object) be itself, and yet change? When it changes, it becomes something else. First there was A, now there is A'. In other words, A has ceased to exist. But that doesn't make sense -- we've completely pushed 'change' out of the picture here." It seems that the only way to allow change (and escape a world frozen in existence-as-persistence) is to allow some kind of "two-ity"; for instance in terms of "whole and part": the "whole" needs to come apart, but the parts still need to be seen as part of the whole.

Frivolous afterthought
Learning to count, first we need to learn to count to one and then two. I believe that learning to count may start much earlier than we normally think. And it may be entangled with moral education. It may start with "One for you... and one for me!" -- which is also based on a whole messy meal coming apart, being shared (fairly), and becoming well-ordered in a sequence of discrete steps :)

"Form is Emptiness, Emptiness is Form" - the Heart Sutra. I think I understand math better after reading this!

This is (maybe) simpler than it seems. Let's consider a simple object: a rock. First, we can see that this rock doesn't really exist to our minds unless it somehow stands out from the background. If there is a pile of rubble at the foot of a landslide, we conceptualize that as a pile of rubble, not as thousands of specific, individual rocks. If we walk across a sandy beach, we don't think that we're crossing billions of very tiny rocks,  though technically that's what sand is. Nor do we think of a mountain as a really, really big rock. The peculiar way our mind categorizes a 'rock' is as a hard, earthen object that can be moved individually.  Mountains are not rocks because we can't move them; sand or rubble are not rocks because we wouldn't normally move it piece by piece (we'd scoop it up in bunches). We don't see a rock until we separate a single object from the background and focus on it as a rock.
Second, assume we could take a rock and stuff it through a wormhole so that it was in a universe of its own. In that (admittedly weird) case, we couldn't really say that it was a 'rock'. It would be the totality of that universe, with nothing to compare it to. We couldn't say whether it was hard or soft, earthen or non-earthen, movable or non-movable, etc, because all of those are comparatives and there is nothing else in that universe to compare it to. For something to be a 'rock' it needs to have a background containing other rocks, or non-rocks; things we can compare it to or measure it against.
Now obviously the rock, the rubble and sand, the mountain, and the universe all exist at the same time (at least as best we can understand). But they don't know themselves to be rock, rubble, sand, mountain, or universe. They are just a whole. The act of constructing a mental object — the act of 'knowing' — means fencing off a part of that whole using comparative measurements; separating 'this' from 'that' within the unity. It's a bit like notching an arrow and pulling the string of a bow. The place where we grip the bowstring becomes a defined point, where it had previously been an indeterminate part of a stretched line; it becomes defined because we consciously pull that point away from the grip of the bow, making a measurable, comparative separation. Without the bow, that point can't be defined; without the definition of that point, the bow can't launch an arrow. We need the unity if string and bow so we can pull out one part of that unity against the rest of that unity. That's how we fire an arrow, and that how we construct a mental object.
When Hegel meets the Dao…

The features of rock versus sand, etc, is a good case study or contemplation of the concept called feature detection. The brain, or neural network, is considered a model-free estimator that creates models or features via neuronal activity. But then the neural network is generating concepts such as neurons, neuronal activity, model-free estimation, feature detection, etc. I prefer your subjective contemplation to the language of neural network theory. Take subjective experience to the limit and there is a unity of the field of awareness with the items of recognition in the stream of experience.

@SystemTheory: If you'd like an even more interesting case study, think about ants.  We tend to see ants as individual organisms, but a case could be made that the actual organism is the ant colony, with each ant equivalent to an individual cell connected by a network of chemical scent trails. Ants don't even eat as individuals;  raw material is processed in the nest into a liquid that is distributed to the colony, much as our own digestive system works. We have a perceptual bias towards unitary organisms, but there's no reason a colony couldn't be seen as a distributed organism.

I have thought much about the human self as woven into the fabric of nature where every living being is an expression of life-spirit and the source of all life-spirit is the Living God or Great Spirit. Black Elk prays to Great Spirit in this way, "A relative I am! A relative to all that is! Give me the eyes to see and the strength to understand that I may be like you! With your power only can I face the winds!" The birds navigate the winds and the bison face into the wind in a storm.  This goes beyond hive-mind or group-mind. But people who over generalize erase each other too.

There was that famous guy who said, "Give me a long enough lever and a place to stand, and I will move that big rock!"

The unity of opposites requires equilibrium, otherwise it would cease to be unity. Thusly, the unity of opposites REQUIRES duality, not non-duality. In fact, any notion of the unity of opposites being non-dualistic would imply that unity itself is not dependent upon cohesion, rather abrasion. This abrasion is obviously a faux merging. For the merging of that which is abrasive and that which is not, is nothing but anti-merger, such as a clash.
Taking this into account, no, the representation of "non-duality" is not present via the unity of opposites. Logically, linguistically and reasonably, it cannot be.
